# How to update value of input that is pulled from an empty array in state?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a table that has inputs in it. For all the inputs, I am setting state and then using the state to set the default values onto form inputs. However, what I'm stuck on and I'm trying to currently figure out is how I can also edit these default values in case I want to edit a record in my table.

I did a ton of research on controlled vs uncontrolled components which I believe my problem is and I switched the `value` to `defaultValue` on my input and it allows me to edit the record but it doesnt show the value that is being set in state.

Basically, I want to be able to view the current record, that has the information that is currently in the input and be able to edit it if necessary.

I have a ton of code so I'll show the little problem I'm having.

```js
import React from "react";

import {
  Table,
  Divider,
  Icon,
  Row,
  Col,
  Popconfirm,
  Modal,
  Input,
  Form,
  Switch,
} from "antd";

import Moment from "moment";

import userprofileService from "../../services/userProfile";
import PdfService from "../../services/pdfService";
import AppController from "../../controllers/AppController";

class AdminInvoices extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      invoiceData: [],
      showInvoice: false,
      viewinvoiceData: [],
      invoiceID: "",
      visible: false,
      showpdfID: "",
      invoicebilledCompany: "",
    };
  }

  selectInvoices = async () => {
    const fetchInvoices = await userprofileService.selectInvoices();

    let filterData = fetchInvoices.filter((item) => item.invoice_status === 1);

    this.setState({ invoiceData: filterData });
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await this.selectInvoices();
  };

  editInvoiceRecord = (e) => {
    // Left off here
    const name = e.target.name;
    const values = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      [name]: values,
    });

    console.log("e target name", name);
    console.log("edit invoice edited data", this.state.viewinvoiceData);
    console.log("record change was recorded as ", values);
  };

  render() {
    const { TextArea } = Input;
    const columns = [
      {
        title: "Invoice Bill Company To",
        dataIndex: "invoice_bill_company_to",
        key: "invoice_bill_company_to",
        width: 150,
      },
      {
        title: "Action",
        key: "action",
        width: 150,
        render: (record) => (
          <span>
            <React.Fragment>
              <Icon
                title="Edit Invoice"
                type="edit"
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => this.viewInvoice(record, 1)}
              />
              <Divider type="vertical" />
              <Icon
                title="View Invoice Details"
                type="eye"
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => this.viewInvoice(record, 2)}
              />
            </React.Fragment>
          </span>
        ),
      },
    ];

    return (
      <div className="adminInvoices">
        <Table
          striped
          bordered
          hover
          variant="dark"
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={this.state.invoiceData}
          scroll={{ x: 1180 }}
        />
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          centered
          width="850px"
        >
          <React.Fragment>
              <Col md={8}>
                <Form.Item label="Invoice Billed Company">
                // This is where im stuck....
                  <Input
                    name={this.state.viewinvoiceData.invoice_bill_company_to}
                    onChange={(e) => this.editInvoiceRecord(e)}
                    value={this.state.viewinvoiceData.invoice_bill_company_to}
                    disabled={this.state.showInvoice ? false : true}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminInvoices;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. It turns out my `name` attribute wasn't named correctly. I changed the name to a hardcoded letter and in my default state added a object with a reference to that name and now I can view and edit the field as necessary.